# Maven: How to fix foreign imports? (in Azure Function)

Tags: java, azure, maven

when I try to start my Azure function locally in Visual Studio Code I get a Maven error as following:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.13.0:package (package-functions) on project ShapefileReader: Execution package-functions of 
goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.13.0:package failed: A required class was missing while executing com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.13.0:package: com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.13.0
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/C:/Users/[user]/.m2/repository/com/microsoft/azure/azure-functions-maven-plugin/1.13.0/azure-functions-maven-plugin-1.13.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/C:/Users/[user]/.m2/repository/com/squareup/okhttp3/okhttp/4.9.1/okhttp-4.9.1.jar
...
[ERROR] urls[201] = file:/C:/Users/[user]/.m2/repository/org/javassist/javassist/3.26.0-GA/javassist-3.26.0-GA.jar
[ERROR] urls[202] = file:/C:/Users/[user]/.m2/repository/com/github/zafarkhaja/java-semver/0.9.0/java-semver-0.9.0.jar
[ERROR] urls[203] = file:/C:/Users/[user]/.m2/repository/org/jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.8.7/org.jacoco.agent-0.8.7-runtime.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] : com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry
```

Running the task as "mvn clean package -e" additionally gives me the ClassNotFoundException:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:471)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:589)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:522)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0 (Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods (Class.java:3166)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod (Class.java:2473)
    at org.reflections.util.Utils.getMemberFromDescriptor (Utils.java:75)
    at org.reflections.util.Utils.getMethodsFromDescriptors (Utils.java:88)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.getMethodsAnnotatedWith (Reflections.java:478)
    at com.microsoft.azure.toolkit.lib.legacy.function.handlers.AnnotationHandlerImpl.findFunctions (AnnotationHandlerImpl.java:52)
    at com.microsoft.azure.maven.function.PackageMojo.findAnnotatedMethods (PackageMojo.java:175)
    at com.microsoft.azure.maven.function.PackageMojo.doExecute (PackageMojo.java:117)
    at com.microsoft.azure.maven.AbstractAzureMojo.execute (AbstractAzureMojo.java:499)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:957)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:289)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:193)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
```

The dependency is in my Maven folder as normally and I can also view the class com.vividsolutions.jt.geom.Geometry in Visual Studio Code so I don't think that it should appear missing. I already tried deleting the dependency from the Maven directory and redownloading it but this did not seem to change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which Maven versions and JDK version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have Maven 3.6.3 and AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.8.10. Also in the pom.xml it says azure.functions.maven.plugin.version=1.13.0 and azure.functions.java.library=1.4.2

Comment: Please try to execute the whole build outside of any IDE plain command line....

Comment: I did and it basically shows the same as in the OP except there is now a PluginExecutionException which I did not see before: ```Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution package-functions of goal com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.13.0:package failed: A required class was missing while executing com.microsoft.azure:azure-functions-maven-plugin:1.13.0:package: com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Geometry```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a possible solution `com.vividsolutions.jts` has been moved to `org.locationtech.jts`. Thus you should provide the jar to your maven build instead of trying to download it from maven repository.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).